# Toolbar style changes in Android 4 when activity called from a static method

Tags: java, android, static, android-toolbar

Found a strange issue in the app.

Toolbar style changes itself just for one acitvity in whole app and only on devices below 5.0 Android version.

[image]

[image]

[image]

All the screens have the same `<include>` field for the toolbar.
The activities, where style changes, are all inflated with a static method:

```
public static void startAsRecent(Context context, TransferTemplate template) {
                Intent starter = new Intent(context, TransferAnotherAccountActivity.class);
                starter.putExtra(TransferCommonActivity.EXTRA_KEY_TEMPLATE, template);
                starter.putExtra(TransferCommonActivity.EXTRA_KEY_IS_RECENT, true);
                context.startActivity(starter);
    }
```

Strange, that it works normail in devices with Android versions abowe 5.0.

What could be the reason of this kind of behavior? And where to look to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you setting theme for individual layout?

Comment: No. Theme is set only for Toolbar layout. Layouts where toolbar included don't have themes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was in inheritance.

`onCreate()` method of inherited activities, where was the problem, called `setContentView()` first, and then `super.OnCreate()`. Still don't understand, why this affected only pre-lollipop devices, but the temporary solution is to make something like this in the superclass.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getContentViewId());
        //other stuff  

}

@LayoutRes
public abstract int getContentViewId();
```